# How to return current time dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a variable which holds the current time when executed, is there a way to update the variable during the process so it holds the latest time.

I'm expecting in increment in the time with every execution ?
I'm not sure if this is possible

**t0**
'2019-09-13 13:23:21'

**t1**
'2019-09-13 13:23:55'

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
eval('start_time')
```

Comment: Any reason to not just run it again when you want the current time?

Comment: @JonClements mainly because I''ll be calling the variable over 20 time so rather than having the same code over and over again, it would be neater to have one variable which I could exec several time

Comment: That's not how variables/eval works... Why not just create a convenience function, something like: `def now(): return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and then instead of where you're trying to do something like `eval('start_time')` just use `now()` instead?

Comment: I agree, that is what functions are made for...

Comment: @JonClements very true I didnt think of that, thanks!